Which subject does the verb "lacks" refer to in this sentence?
"Groupthink is a phenomenon observed when a group of people get together to make decisions on a particular issue with the aim of achieving agreement and harmony, but lacks critical thinking and contingency planning."
I don't understand what word " lacks critical thinking and contingency planning": "Groupthink", "a group of people", or "the aim", or maybe some other word.

Only 'a group of people' is possible. I would prefer 'lack' (plural).
